System.Outofmemoryexception in windows service GraphQl post request
I have a windows service running once per day that gets some information in a GraphQl post request like so:
        try
        {
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonQuery);
            
            var response = client2.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://gql.waveapps.com/graphql/public", json).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Falhou query à Wave.");
            }

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //obJson data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<obJson>(content.Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"{", "{").Replace("}\"", "}").Replace(@"\", ""));
            //_loggerError.Error($"content do json {content.ToString()}");

            obJson data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<obJson>(content.ToString());

            client2.Dispose();

            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"Não teve sucesso em obter dados do Wave - {ex.Message}");
            _loggerError.Error($"Não teve sucesso em obter dados do Wave - {ex.Message}");

            return null;
        }

It started all of a sudden giving in the client's server a system.outofmemoryexception and I have no idea why.
I have searched for a way to correct this, however it doesn't seem to be anything in the code that gives infinite loop, and I can't seem to find a way to set buffer options..
Would anyone be able to help?

I would check for memory leaks - how do you handle HttpClient or other unmanageable resources?

Hi @LukaszSzczygielek, thank you for the suggestion. I am creating a GraphQlHttpClient with options Media type application/json, base address and authorization, and you can see at the end that after getting the data I use client2.dispose().

In the exception section, you don't dispose.
